# FireBase dispatch function doesn't save to realtime DB

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

I need some help with a realtimeDB issue.Am using NuxtJS to store state and dispatch the state to DB.
My code is working fine regarding saving into to the DB. Whenever I want to edit it, I receive this 400 BAD Request error.
The same thing happens when i manually try to update info withing the Firebase realtime DB, I can't edit the line with the text.

ERROR:

```
vendor.js:387 PUT https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/posts.json-MI-Jym0mdX5jNNP89UH.json?auth=BIGKEY 400 (Bad Request)
```

My component

```
<template>
  <div class="admin-post-page">
    <section class="update-form">
      <AdminPostForm :post="loadedPost" @submit="onSubmitted" />
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AdminPostForm from "@/components/Admin/AdminPostForm";

export default {
  layout: "admin",
  middleware: ['check-auth', 'auth'],
  components: {
    AdminPostForm
  },
  asyncData(context) {
    return context.app.$axios
      .$get(
        process.env.baseUrl + "/posts/" +
          context.params.postId +
          ".json"
      )
      .then(data => {
        return {
          loadedPost: { ...data, id: context.params.postId }
        };
      })
      .catch(e => context.error());
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmitted(editedPost) {
      this.$store.dispatch("editPost", editedPost).then(() => {
        this.$router.push("/admin");
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The method from store is:

```
 editPost(vuexContext, editedPost) {
        return this.$axios
          .$put(
            "https://XXXX.com/posts.json" +
              editedPost.id +
              ".json?auth=" +
              vuexContext.state.token,
            editedPost
          )
          .then(res => {
            vuexContext.commit("editPost", editedPost);
          
          })
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }
```

And my rules are:

```
{
   "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": true
     }
 }
```

If you can help me with info regarding why I am not allowed, would owe you a lot!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL contains two `.json` extensions, which won't work. You should only add `.json` after the full path of the JSON you are trying to write/update:

```
this.$axios
      .$put(
        "https://XXXX.com/posts/" +
          editedPost.id +
          ".json?auth=" +
          vuexContext.state.token,
        editedPost
      )
```